# Why session get expired

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7.5

We have an application (`ASP Dot Net , Framework 4.0`) in production which is deployed on `IIS 7.5 window server 2012`. Every day this application gets around `4000 requests`, but the problem we are facing for the last couple of days is that some of the users complain their session gets expired. We have checked the application and don't see any error that can get the session expired. We've checked the IIS setting and pool setting, but we don't see any reason fair enough to sort out the issue.

Please help us in this regard to get this sorted out.

---

Probably I need to give more detail that helps you resolve my issue.
We work in professional organisation where we run many application on IIS for our clients. The issue we receiving is coming on one of the same application we build for our new client and deployed on IIS 8.0 server 2012.

In web config of our application time out is for one hour and further we make sure that we shouldn't route the user to session expire page if any other error comes. Now after making these changes we are pretty sure that issue should not be due to application configuration or due to the structure of it.
Now we are concern about the IIS. The different thing this time is we are using IIS 8.0 not IIS 7.5 which we are using on our all different servers for different applications.
Some of the IIS configuration you might be interested

1. we have dedicated pool for the application further pool is configured 2.0 because application is on the framework 3.5.
2. maximum worker process = 1
3. Pool recycle in 28 hours

Let me know if you could guide me anything specifically if that is related to IIS 8.0 because we are thinking of reverting back to 7.5, its our production application and clients are keep complaining about it.

Comment: This will not will enough to give you answer. Because no body can understand. You can do reverse engineering by checking any one can do activity within some day on server like new framework install, window update, hot fix installed, new software installed etc. so you can un-install that and try again.

Comment: You will have to add or enable application level logging to see for all sessions when they actually expire and for what. Without that initial data, you won't be able to get started

Answer (score 0):

The Life time of a session of a user is set by the developer / yourself. So you have privilege to set the time a user session time out at the desired time. Here is the format of th declaration in the web.config.

```
<sessionState mode="Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer"
              cookieless="true|false"
              timeout="number of minutes"
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
              sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
              stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"/>
```

You can set the creation of cookies to true or false
Decide / dictate where the session information needs to be stored(server, database..)
These are some of the links that can help.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx)

[MSDN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa303455.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you might have allocated the default application pool for this application in the IIS and the same application pool might have been shared among other applications too.

Step1: You should allocate separate application pool for each site in the IIS.

Step2: in application pool --> advanced settings --> Change the maximum worker process count to 1

If the above solution is not working, better try the solution which is given in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781036(WS.10).aspx

Hope this helps.